# Unable to submit the form via ajax call back function in jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have done an ajax to prevent the form submition for validation

I am doing the validation by storing the ajaxs return in a hidden variable...

my form is not submitted due to return false in my else loop

after the Ajax return success i am submitting the form from jquery but i am getting

Uncaught Type Error: Property 'submit' of object # is not a function 
Please Help me .....

i am just storing a value 1 in the hidden field which i am getting from the test.php ....

but the console shows error on $("#foo")[0].submit();

if i click submit second time the JavaScript check the hidden value=1 and enters into true loop ...then its get submitting

Thank you in advance

```
<form id="foo" name="foo" action="pop.php"  method="get">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="bar1" name="bar1" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="statushidden" id="statushidden" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        var status = validdata();

        if (document.getElementById("statushidden").value=="1")
        {
            alert("true loop");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("false loop");
            return false;
        }

    });

    function validdata()
    {
        var url = "test.php"; 
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           beforeSend: function(){},
           url: url,
           data: $("#foo").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               document.getElementById("statushidden").value=data;
               console.log($("#foo")[0].submit);
               $("#foo")[0].submit(); ///// SHOWING Error on this line///////      
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need tell the  `contentType:"Application/Json"`

before your click method. you prevent the default action. once ajax finishes, you call the submit method.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        // your rest code. 
    });
```

try like this for the ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
url:url,
data:$("#foo").serialize(),
contentType:"Application/Json";
.... your success blocks. 
});
```

if you have trouble for submit method. then try like this

```
$("form").submit(); ///// Error on this line will be fixed///////
```

Comment: @user1386579 your form has GET method. so it's not posting the data. change it to POST

Comment: changed to post still showing error on form submit line in jquery ajax..

is there any other syntax to submit form from jquery Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Please check by removing [0] from function like below

```
function validdata()
    {
        var url = "test.php"; 
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           beforeSend: function(){},
           url: url,
           data: $("#foo").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               document.getElementById("statushidden").value=data;
               $("#foo").submit(); ///// Removed [0] from your given snippet ///////      
           }
        });
    }
```